# How to wrap text without spaces in React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My attempt: https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-smoke-bhudq .
It does not wrap but rather overflows to the right, over the "HELLO".
It also seems like `maxWidth` is not effective.

So can anyone update the example so that the text is confined to a certain max width, and broke into multiple lines?

Comment: You are not setting your CSS correctly. You are using CSS props as if they were element props. They are not, they belong to the `style` prop. Your question is the equivalent of forgetting a semicolon and asking about it on SO, which is likely why you received a downvote.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that you could do that, since I have seen e.g. `fullWidth` as props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<Box
  component="div"
  flexWrap="wrap"
  wordWrap="break-word"
  ...
>
```

you'll want something like

```
<Box
  style={{
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    wordWrap: 'break-word',
    ...
  }}
>
```