# MUI Grid children taking too much space

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x

I'm trying to render two large blobs of text side by side, each of which may or may not include new lines or any whitespace. I'm attempting to use a Material UI `Grid` however the grids are not behaving the way I would expect.

I have created a small example here showing my issue https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-forked-rzzk26?file=/index.js

Based on the background color of the boxes added to the grid, the grid itself is working correctly however the text is overflowing
[image]

How can I cause the long text in the blue box to wrap to a new line and never overflow outside its parents bounds?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexWrap: "wrap" with specific width. If it is not working then provide a code.

Comment: Do you mean something like `<Grid container wrap="wrap">` ? That doesn't apper to change anything. The full code in a running example can be seen here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mui-forked-rzzk26?file=/index.js

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: After a bt of debugging, I determined the culperate was this `Box` that was wrapping all other components in my application:

```
<Box component="main" sx={{ flexGrow: 1, p: 3 }}>
  {children}
</Box>
```

Adding `overflow: "hidden"` to this components style resolved my issues

This answer [How to wrap text without spaces in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60550875/how-to-wrap-text-without-spaces-in-react) got me to a working example. Its still not working in my main project but at least I've narrowed it down to something external to the grid causing issues.

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <Box
          color={"red"}
          style={{
            flexWrap: "wrap",
            wordWrap: "break-word",
          }}
        >
          {requestContent}
        </Box>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <Box
          color={"primary.secondary"}
          style={{
            flexWrap: "wrap",
            wordWrap: "break-word",
          }}
        >
          {responseContent}
        </Box>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```